# freeRadius service not installed on CentOS 7 when installed from Source

Tags: freeradius

OS: CentOS 7
freeRadius - 3.0.16

I have installed freeRadius 3.0.16 from a source download as yum did not show me any available duplicates of the desired version. I have used an archived source file (.tar.gz) to install radius. I used the commands outlined in their technical documentation:

./configure
./make
make install

My server works correctly and as intended after testing and debugging, but I am not able to run radius as a service. When I use **systemctl status freeradius** (or radiusd), the file/service is not found.

When checking my /etc/system directory for the installed services, there is not a freeradius.service or radiusd.service installed. However all of my documentation leads me to believe that this should have been installed as part of the process. Is there a specific library or dependency that I am missing that  I require?

Thanks!

Edit:

This is what happens when I attempt to add the freeradius.service from the debain folder. I am unsure of how to edit this file to get things to work correctly or if it is even possible.

---

```
[root@localhost system]# systemctl enable freeradius.service

[root@localhost system]# systemctl start freeradius.service
Job for freeradius.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status freeradius.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

[root@localhost system]# systemctl status freeradius.service
● freeradius.service - FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/freeradius.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-04-27 08:31:29 EDT; 271ms ago
     Docs: man:radiusd(8)
           man:radiusd.conf(5)
           http://wiki.freeradius.org/
           http://networkradius.com/doc/
  Process: 22469 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/freeradius $FREERADIUS_OPTIONS -Cxm -lstdout (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Apr 27 08:31:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server.
Apr 27 08:31:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit freeradius.service entered failed state.
Apr 27 08:31:29 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: freeradius.service failed.


-------------------
Freeradius.service content

[root@localhost system]# cat freeradius.service
[Unit]
Description=FreeRADIUS multi-protocol policy server
After=network.target
Documentation=man:radiusd(8) man:radiusd.conf(5) http://wiki.freeradius.org/ http://networkradius.com/doc/

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/freeradius/freeradius.pid
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/freeradius
ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/freeradius $FREERADIUS_OPTIONS -Cxm -lstdout
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/freeradius $FREERADIUS_OPTIONS
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
ExecReload=/usr/sbin/freeradius $FREERADIUS_OPTIONS -Cxm -lstdout
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
[root@localhost system]#
```

Comment: Your config is failing the pre-flight check.

Run ``/usr/sbin/freeradius -Cxm -lstdout`` to see what's going wrong.  Might just be a permissions issue if it previously worked.

Comment: Ugh that's probably the issue, you're using the *Debian* unit, not the *RHEL* unit and the Debian unit refers to the main binary as ``freeradius`` but the Centos one uses ``radiusd``.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which documentation is leading you to believe that, but I know for certain that installing from source will not install a unit file for systemd.  This is true for source packages for the vast majority of open source software, as installing support files is usually delegated to OS specific packages.

To manually install the unit file, on RHEL/Centos `/etc/systemd/system/` is generally used for administrator installed unit files, so should be as simple as:

```
cp freeradius-server/redhat/radiusd.service /etc/systemd/system/
systemctl start radiusd
```

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how to manually do this? My google-fu is failing me.